# Why UnCaught Exception occurs in a TabActivity?

Tags: java, android

I have created a TabActivity and added TabWidget and frame to the layout.

I have four other Activity classes with single label in each Activity. Four tabs are associated with four tabs.

When I am trying to launch the application in emulator, I am getting the below exception

> 09-03 23:24:43.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(450):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 09-03 23:24:43.905:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(450):     at
>   android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:295)
>   09-03 23:24:43.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(450):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
>   09-03 23:24:43.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(450):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)

```
public class TabHome extends TabActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TabHost tabHost=getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
    Resources res=getResources();

    Intent intent;

    intent=new Intent().setClass(this, MyMap.class);        
    tabSpec=   tabHost.newTabSpec("Maps").setIndicator("Maps",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(intent);       
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    intent=new Intent().setClass(this, MyStash.class);      
    tabSpec=  tabHost.newTabSpec("Stash").setIndicator("Stash",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(intent);      
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    intent=new Intent().setClass(this, MyList.class);       
    tabSpec=  tabHost.newTabSpec("List").setIndicator("List",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(intent);        
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    intent=new Intent().setClass(this, MySearch.class);     
    tabSpec=  tabHost.newTabSpec("Search").setIndicator("Search",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(intent);        
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);


}
```

Comment: Please add some code snippets from the layout and the tab activity..

Comment: Can you add please the xml layout and the full error log pls?

Comment: @Katturaja: There will normally be a "Caused by..." entry in the logcat which will indicate which line of your code is causing the problem. The exception that you show only references android code and doesn't really help.

Comment: When and all an activity Force Closes? From code point of view, Do you think i have missed something? Or Somewhere I have to check for / set some configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed to mention the following attributes to main.xml

android:id="@android:id/tabhost" in TabHost tag

and

android:id="@android:id/tabs" in TabWidget tag

and

android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" in FrameLayout tag.

Thanks all for your help!